# defaultdict how to get sum of all values in a list?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
models = [Url1, Url2, Url3, Url4, Url5, Url6, Url7, Url8, Url9, Url10]
d = defaultdict(list)

for model in models:

    getids = model.objects.values_list('keyword', 'score')
    for kw, score in getids:
        d[kw].append(score)
```

This makes 'd' output this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {198: [-70, 0, 5, -70, 5, 5, 0, 0, -50, -70],     
199: [0, -70, -70, -70, -70, -70, -100, -70, -70, -70]})
```

How to make it return this:

```
defaultdict({198: -245, 199: -660}) #sum of all numbers inside lists, returned as values to both keys.
```

I tried for looping but deafultdict doesn't seem to work like normal lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = defaultdict(int)

for model in models:

    getids = model.objects.values_list('keyword', 'score')
    for kw, score in getids:
        d[kw] += score
```

Comment: The key here is using `int` as the default factory so that you can keep a running sum.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict` comprehensive to take the sum of each values

```
 summed = {k: sum(v) for (k, v) in d.items()}
 print(summed) 
 >>> {198: -245, 199: -660}
```

Also, `defaultdict` acts like  a `dictionary`, not as a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace list corresponding to the keys with its sum.

```
for i in d:
     d[i] = sum(d[i])
```